# How are properties shared across instances using javascript prototypes

Tags: javascript, inheritance, instance-variables, prototype-chain

My understanding of prototypical inheritance is every object has a prototype property. If a property doesn't exist on an object then it's prototype object is checked, so on and so on up the chain.

In this example my prototype object is a simple object with a counter property.

I'm expecting every instance to share the same prototype but they appear to get new instances. The output of this code is 00, I was expecting 01.

Am I missing something obvious?

```
"use strict";

var ConstructorFunction = function () {};

ConstructorFunction.prototype = {
    counter: 0,
    count: function () {
        return this.counter++;
    }
};

var a = new ConstructorFunction();
var b = new ConstructorFunction();

$("#output").append(a.count());
$("#output").append(b.count());
```

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hdA6G/5/

Comment: You have the logic inverted. The property should be unique to the instance and the method should be in the prototype to be shared.

Comment: I'm doing that deliberately. I want the counter property shared across all instances.

Comment: I see, check my answer, a closure is what you need here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is true that the prototype properties are shares across all instances. The problem is that you never change the prototype property. Take a look at your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hdA6G/9/) with some extra logs:

```
"use strict";

var ConstructorFunction = function () {};

ConstructorFunction.prototype = {
    counter: 0,
    count: function () {
        return ++this.counter;
    }
};

var a = new ConstructorFunction();
var b = new ConstructorFunction();

$("#output").append(a.hasOwnProperty("counter") + " "); //false
a.count();
$("#output").append(a.hasOwnProperty("counter") + " "); //true
```

As you see, as soon as you call `++this.counter`, a local property will be created which will be used from that on.

I **assume** that this is what happens:

`++this.counter` is interpreted as `this.counter = this.counter + 1`. First, the part right of the equal sign is evaluated and since your instance doesn't have a `counter` property, the counter property of the prototype is used. The value of this property will be added to 1 and then assigned to `this.counter`, which now creates a local property, in the same way that it does, when you assign a property that hasn't been there at all, like `a.xy = 1`. `xy` will be a local property of the instance in that case.

**EDIT**

There are two workarounds that still would let you use the prototype property:

1) explicitly set the prototype property inside of the `count` method:

```
ConstructorFunction.prototype.count = function() {
    return ++this.constructor.prototype.counter;
};
```

2) call the count method with `apply` and use the prototype as context:

```
a.count.apply(a.constructor.prototype);
```

**BUT**, if you set the `prototype` property the way you did, you will get problems with both of these methods.

```
 ConstructorFunction.prototype = {
     //...
 };
```

This overrides the complete prototype object and therefore also the constructor property of it. The constructor property will now point to the next higher object in the prototype chain, the `Object` object. To fix that, you could either set the constructor manually after you assigned the prototype object:

```
ConstructorFunction.prototype.constructor = ConstructorFunction;
```

or assign every property of the prototype object seperately:

```
ConstructorFunction.prototype.counter = 0;
ConstructorFunction.prototype.count = function () {
    return ++this.counter;
};
```

Comment: I was trying to figure this out after I posted my solution and came up with the wrong explanation. It seems to be a simple case of property overriding a property with the same name then.

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer I was looking for. Just as you posted I found this: http://sporto.github.io/blog/2013/02/22/a-plain-english-guide-to-javascript-prototypes/ ** New / updated properties are assigned to the object, not to the prototype **

Answer (score 3):

Consider using a closure so you can keep that variable private and shared across instances:

```
var Class = (function ClassModule() {

  var counter = 0;

  function Class() {}

  Class.prototype = {

    count: function() {
      return counter++;
    }
  };

  return Class;
}());

var class1 = new Class();
var class2 = new Class();

console.log(class1.count()); //=> 0
console.log(class2.count()); //=> 1
```

The `counter` variable is kept in context with the closure (module pattern), and won't be duplicated with each new instance.

Comment: This is what I want, but more importantly I want to understand what is happening in the code I posted.

Answer (score 1):

In prototype based OOD, sharing means to share the same definition and use it for different contexts. If you need a static property to be shared between contexts you can do as given below

```
var ConstructorFunction = function (context) {
    this.count = function () {
        return context + "," + (++this.counter) + "," + (++ConstructorFunction.staticCounter);
    };
};

ConstructorFunction.prototype.counter = 0;

ConstructorFunction.staticCounter = 0;

var context1 = new ConstructorFunction("context1");
var context2 = new ConstructorFunction("context2");

$("#output").append(context1.count());
$("#output").append(" ");
$("#output").append(context2.count());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hdA6G/1/

and a better way to define it

```
var ConstructorFunction = function (context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.counter = 0;
};
ConstructorFunction.staticCounter = 0;

ConstructorFunction.prototype.count = function () {
    return this.context + "," + (++this.counter) + "," + (++ConstructorFunction.staticCounter);
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hdA6G/3/

Comment: Does that mean the object assigned to the prototype property is cloned for each new instance?

Comment: it is not cloned. but re-used in different in contexts.

Comment: Things defined in `ConstructorFunction` is instantiated and cloned. Things defined in prototype is executed in the context of each intstance. So it is recommended to define properties in constructor and methods in properties.

Comment: Please see my updated code sample. I think where I had the function declared confused what I was actually asking. If the object isn't cloned how can counter have two different values? The code that sets counter=0 must run more than once.

Comment: properties will be cloned and assigned to each instance but methods won't be cloned. methods will be re-used by executing in the context of each intstance.

Comment: I have confirmed what you are saying with this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/hdA6G/8/ the properties are cloned, the functions are not.

Answer (score 0):

You have your inheritance backwards, the prototype inherits from the base object. I think this is more similar to what you are trying to accomplish.

```
function MyObject () {
    this.count = 0;
};

ConstructorFunction.prototype = {
    counter: function () {
        return this.count++;
    },
    print: function () {
        return this.count;
    }
};


Var Foo = new MyObject();

console.log(Foo.counter()); // 1
console.log(Foo.counter()); // 2
console.log(Foo.print()); // 2
```

I hope this helps.

**edit**

If you want your counter shared across all instances then it should go in you base object.

```
function MyObject () {
    this.count = 0;
    this.counter = function () {
        return this.count++; //may not need the this
    }
};
```

Comment: In my example I am creating two instances, I want them both to share the same property from the base object.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I am new to Javascrpt and while experimenting I came across something similar, so wanted to put in my 2 cents.

It seems every object gets its own copy of variables declared in prototype once it is instantiated using `new`. From then on, accessing using `this` will do the usual look up and find the private copy which is operated upon.

However, if you create a prototype variable **after** creation of all objects, that variable will be shared and behaves like static. I think it is fairly simple to reason why this happens, but, nonetheless, I found this to be an interesting hack. I am not sure if this is a bug in technical specs that might be resolved in future versions, or side effect of standard behavior, so don't know if this is reliable. I am not even sure if this is a newly introduced 'feature' in later versions of the language. Actually, I started googling about this fact and came across this post.

Try this code.

```
var Worker = function (name) {
    this.name = name;
}
Worker.prototype.jobs = 0;
Worker.prototype.Work = function () {
    console.log("jobs finished", this.name, ++this.jobs);
}
Worker.prototype.WorkCount = function () {
    console.log("work count", this.name, this.workCount);
}
var ca = new Worker("ca");
var cb = new Worker("cb");
ca.Work();// shows 1
cb.Work();// shows 1
ca.WorkCount();// shows undefined
cb.WorkCount();// shows undefined
Worker.prototype.workCount = 2;
ca.WorkCount();// shows 2
cb.WorkCount();// shows 2
```